# How to specify subjective columns for a formula within a function

Tags: r, function, functional-programming, manova

Consider `dat1` created here:

```r
dat1 <- data.frame(Region = rep(c("r1","r2"), each = 100),
                   State = rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 10),
                   Loc = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),each = 5),
                   ID = rep(c(1:10), each=2),
                   var1 = rnorm(200),
                   var2 = rnorm(200),
                   var3 = rnorm(200),
                   var4 = rnorm(200),
                   var5 = rnorm(200))
```

I want to write a function that will allow me to specify the data, grouping variable (`Region`,`State`, or `Loc`), and row names of the variables (`var1`:`var5`) with which I want it to conduct a manova and return the results in tidy format. Running the function would look something like this: `manova.test(dat = dat1, groupvar = "Region", cols = 5:9)`

The function would look something like this (which doesn't work):

```r
manova.test <- function(dat, groupvar, cols){
   var.mat <- as.matrix(dat[, cols])
   group.man <- manova(cbind(var.mat) ~ groupvar, data = dat)
   summary(group.man)
 }
```

How do you do this? I am especially confused about how to specify the formula in this format!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get` to return the named object within the function. The drawback is that the variable will be labelled `get(groupvar)` in the summary, so I renamed it within your function:

```r
set.seed(1)
dat1 <- data.frame(Region = rep(c("r1","r2"), each = 100),
                   State = rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 10),
                   Loc = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),each = 5),
                   ID = rep(c(1:10), each=2),
                   var1 = rnorm(200),
                   var2 = rnorm(200),
                   var3 = rnorm(200),
                   var4 = rnorm(200),
                   var5 = rnorm(200))

manova.test <- function(dat, groupvar, cols){
    var.mat <- as.matrix(dat[, cols])
    group.man <- manova(cbind(var.mat) ~ get(groupvar), data = dat)
    s <- summary(group.man)
    dimnames(s$stats)[[1]][1] <- groupvar
    s
}

manova.test(dat = dat1, groupvar = "Region", cols = 5:9)
#>            Df   Pillai approx F num Df den Df Pr(>F)
#> Region      1 0.015933   0.6282      5    194 0.6784
#> Residuals 198
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you are just worried about the formula, you were almost there. This should work

```
manova.test <- function(df, groupvar) {
  manova(cbind(var1, var2) ~ df[[groupvar]], data = df)
}

manova.test(dat1, "Region")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach based on win-vector.com/blog/2018/09/r-tip-how-to-pass-a-formula-to-lm/, the cool thing about this solution is that you can easily extend groupvar for multiple columns

```
manova.test <- function(dat, groupvar, cols){
  paster <- function(x){
    paste(x,collapse = " + ")
  }

  groupvar <- dat %>% select({{groupvar}}) %>% names()

  var.mat <- as.matrix(dat %>% select({{cols}}))

  f <- paste("cbind(var.mat)", paster(groupvar), sep = " ~ " ) %>% as.formula()

  model <- eval(bquote(   manova(.(f), data = dat)))
  summary(model)
}

manova.test(dat1,c(Region,Loc),cols = c(var1:var5))
```